# Parsec: How to silence parser errors about white spaces

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have the following parser for parsing BASH-like lines containing redirection.

```
lineRedirect :: P.Parsec String () String
lineRedirect = do
  lcmd <- P.spaces *> (P.many1 command P.<?> "command")
  P.char '>'
  rcmd <- P.spaces *> (P.many1 command P.<?> "redirection target")
  return $ (intercalate ";" lcmd) ++ " ++ " ++ (intercalate ";" rcmd)   
  where
    command :: P.Parsec String () String
    command = P.many1 P.alphaNum <* P.spaces
```

It seems to be working just fine, but I'd like to silence any "expecting space" or "expecting whitespace" that appear.

For example:

```
> P.parseTest lineRedirect "   > target"
parse error at (line 1, column 4):
unexpected ">"
expecting space or command
```

I'd like to have just "expecting command" here.

```
> P.parseTest lineRedirect "invalid! > target"
parse error at (line 1, column 8):
unexpected "!"
expecting letter or digit, white space or ">"
```

Same here, without the "white space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After realizing that `spaces` is already a composite parser with its own error message, everything was easy...

Here is what I came up with:

```
lineRedirect :: P.Parsec String () (String, String)
lineRedirect = do
  cmd <- spaces' *> command
  P.char '>'
  tgt <- spaces' *> target
  return (cmd, tgt)

  where
    command :: P.Parsec String () String
    command = (P.many1 (P.noneOf ">") P.<?> "command")  <* spaces'

    target :: P.Parsec String () String
    target = (P.many1 P.anyChar P.<?> "redirection target") <* spaces' <* P.eof

    spaces' = P.skipMany (P.space P.<?> "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work

```
lineRedirect = do
  lcmd <- P.try (P.spaces *> P.many1 command) P.<?> "command"
  ...
```

I don't like the `try`, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Even doing something similar to the 'command' function still makes the parser complain about spaces.

Comment: @JanSynáček Edited and tested. This works, but there might be a more efficient way.